# Simple For Loop through a specified Range defined by last row

Tags: excel, loops, delete-row

I am trying a relatively simply code that does not work. I am trying to loop through a specified range and delete every row in which the first column's cell does not equal another specific cell. The loop should iterate through a range beginning with cell "A11" and finish at the LR, or the reverse. I have tried many different variations of last row as well as the for loop. I can't understand why code as simple as this will not work though. The code is below:

```
Dim sht5 As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Set sht5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
With sht5
For i = LR To Range("A11") step -1
    If i <> Range("B9").Value Then
        Rows(i).Delete shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next i
End With
```

Comment: So close!  In your `For i = ...` change `Range("A11")` to `Range("A11").Row`.  This is because you're going to go from for [lastRow] to the 11th row. Just using `Range("A11")` doesn't tell Excel what you want to use in that range.  Just add `.Row` to specify the row# to be used.  Quick question, is your `B9` determined because it's two rows less than your `A11`? Or some other reason? (just thinking, because if `B9` is determined by where your `Range("A11")` is, then we can use `Offset()` instead of "magic numbers".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim sht5 As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long
    Set sht5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    With sht5
    For I=LR to 11 step -1
    if cells(i,1).value<>range("B9").Value Then
            Rows(i).Delete shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next i
    End With
```